# How to split a `cstring` in nim

Tags: nim-lang

Currently, I am converting `cstring` to `string` using `$` operator from `cstrutils`. There is a `string.split` in `strutils` module.

Is there a way to split a `cstring` e.g.

```
let a : cstring = "hello world"
let b = a.split("o")
# let b = ($a).split("o"))   # work `$a` is string.
```

Comment: What do you want your cstring split into, a seq[string]?

Answer (score 3):

A C string is just a C string, which is a pointer to a block of characters terminated with char(0), \x0.

In Nim C strings are mostly used when we use C libs which expects C strings as arguments. Nim strings are an opaque object with a length field and a data buffer, which is zero terminated and compatible to C strings, so we can pass that buffer to C libs. So from Nim strings we get the Cstring for free, but to get a Nim string from a C string means to allocate a new entity and copy content.

C language itself has not many operations for working with strings, we would have to use libraries, glib from gtk for example. Splitting a C string would mean allocating two new strings, or at least allocating one new and inserting \x0 to the old to mark the end. Problem with C strings is generally, that when we allocate them we have to care that we deallocate it to avoid memory leaks.

So the recommendation is: Use Nim strings from the beginning. You can just pass them to C libs directly, the Nim compiler is smart and passes the actual buffer. C libs creates copies of the string in most cases. If not, and the C lib would use the actual C string internally, you would have to care that the Nim string is not freed too early by the Nim GC, maybe call gc_ref() on the string. There may be rare conditions where you may want to really use C strings in Nim, maybe to save memory? You may do that when you know that you do not want to do operations with that string, like appending, splitting, substitution and all that what Nim strings provide. There is a section about Nim strings and C strings in the Nim beginner book, see http://ssalewski.de/nimprogramming.html#_strings

Comment: I am using nim-generated C code in an existing C codebase.  So `const char*` to `cstring` seemed like a natural choice to begin with. As I extend the functionality in nim code, `cstring` showing its lack of power. Thanks for the book link.

Comment: cstring is Compatible String. It is used also with Javascript, and it helps to have it memorized as Compatible rather than C.

Comment: Yes, and it is stated right in the book already: "Nim has also the data type cstring, called "compatible string" in modern Nim, which matches the strings in C language if we compile as usual with C backend." But for us who use Nim since many years without considering JS webdev, we compare Nim strings to C langauge strings first. Can you tell us some more about Javascript strings and how Nim strings are converted to Javascript strings?

Comment: Dilawar, using nim-generated C code in an existing C codebase sounds really complicated. Personally I would avoid it, one problem is when the GC frees variables that are used in C still.

Comment: @Salewski I call a nim function with char* as the only argument and the function returns a char* after processing. Additionally pushing the data to a database over network. Other option is to do it via socket server/client or pipes.  Seems liked a good use case to learn nim a bit. Book is great!

Comment: C strings, as in C-language strings, are emphatically _not_ pointers; they are character arrays. The Standard is very clear about this, e.g., [here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) and [here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1). Functions that process strings _do_ take `char *` arguments since arrays decay to pointers to their first element in most expressions.